# Why a UIViewController would stay in memory

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller

Assuming that a view controller is created like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SomeViewController *someViewController;

...

self.someViewController = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithView:imgView];
[self addChildViewController:self.someViewController];

self.someViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.mainView addSubview:self.someViewController.view];
```

Why would it not get released by the following?

```
__weak MainViewController *weakSelf = self;
    self.someViewController.didCloseBlock = ^{

        [weakSelf.someViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [weakSelf.someViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
        [weakSelf.someViewController removeFromParentViewController];

        weakSelf.someViewController = nil;

    };
```

I can tell it's not getting released because if I keep opening and closing the view controller (creating a new instance each time I open one), it causes low memory warnings (and then a crash on iOS5), and in `SomeViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning`, I see a log for the number of times I've created a new SomeViewController. For example, when I get the memory warning after opening 9 new SomeViewControllers, I will get 9 didReceiveMemoryWarning logs, indicating that I have 9 SomeViewController instances in memory, even though I'm nilling each one out in the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're retaining your view once in your property with the strong annotation and again with `self.someViewController = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithView:imgView];`

Using the synthesized variable should get rid of this:
`_someViewController = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithView:imgView];`

If you're not using ARC, you can use `self.someViewController = [[[SomeViewController alloc] initWithView:imgView] autorelease];`

I'd probably go for the first option, ARC or not though.

Comment: Are you sure about this? This is how I always see it done. I am using ARC. How would you change my property declaration?

Comment: If you are using ARC, this is wrong. You can do `self.someViewController = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithView:imgView];`without any issue.

Comment: You shouldn't need to change your property declaration, just use the synthesized object when you allocate it. `_someViewController = ` instead of `self.someViewController = `

Comment: @JackyBoy is correct, this actually shouldn't make a difference under ARC. Could give it a shot anyway, but it may not fix your issue. If it doesn't, I'll just delete the answer.

Comment: Additionally, you could try defining it as weak instead of strong, or taking it out of your property declaration altogether if there's no reason for it to be there and declare it as a private ivar.

Answer (score 0):

You are just setting the block `didCloseBlock`, nothing else actually. Do you execute it?

Comment: Yes, didCloseBlock is executed every time the view controller is closed.

Comment: A wild guess: don't put it as a property of the object that you actually want to release.